# How to give edit rights to own records for a user in openerp 7?

Tags: odoo

I would like to implement the following scenario.

- User must be able to see all the records and should be able to edit only his own records

Is it possible to do it in openerp 7 and if possible how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Record rule so User can see only his records and create Access Control List so User can edit those records.

Record rule --> Settings/Technical/Security/Record Rules

> Create a Record rule for your object and add a specific domain so user
>   can see only his record.

Access Control List --> Settings/Technical/Security/Access Control List

> Create a Access Control List and add name, object,
>   Access(Read/Edit/Delete/Create) and save it. As per your need, you
>   need to tick Write Access, Save it and Check it.

Comment: Hi,Thanks priyesh for your reply. i knew this option already and my context is quite different. User must see(i.e view)all records but should edit only his own records. so i have to display him all the records and should give edit permission only to records that he created. Hope you understand the scenario and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a functional field which returns false if the record is created by the logged in user else true and in the view add a group with attributes readonly if the functional field's value is true and move all the fields to this group and also add the functional field invisible as invisible in the view

Comment: Thanks Anom for your reply, the above lines give write permission to some group and read permission to some group. i would like to give write access based on the record's create_uid. I should edit my own record and view all records. Please guide me if possible.